# infragistics chart issue >> Page. RegisterRequiresPostBack can only be called on controls that implementIPostBackDataHandler

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I have an web application Version 4.5  in which i am using  `infragistics` control chart (version 4.0.20041.28) When run, it gives the error:

> RegisterRequiresPostBack can only be called on controls that implementIPostBackDataHandler

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Switch from infragistic to other option, this charts are very slow. Take a look to the version they have using html 5 or try to use other one.

Comment: Thanks  Steve . after some research i found that if u update ultrachart dll version .. fixed this issue ...